# Wordpress rewrite rules conflicting with real paths and filenames

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm recreating my employers website, it currently uses WordPress,

I have created a new directory within the /public_html/ folder named `dev`. While the `dev` folder is empty - It will display directory contents as expected. The moment I throw an `index.php` file in there, I get sent back to a 404 error.

The contents of `index.php` is simply `<h1>Working</h1>`

Looking into the .htaccess of the primary directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It appears that it should already be ignoring the rule if the requested filename is infact a real file or directory.

The entire .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
#The next line modified by DenyIP
order allow,deny
#The next line modified by DenyIP
#deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName ant.com.au

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Definitely looks like there should be no conflict whatsoever trying to navigate to a literal directory and/or file

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you using default permalink structure?

Comment: you get wordpress 404 error page or webserver 404 error page?

Comment: [Example](http://www.ant.com.au/dev/) - Standard Wordpress replacement of the ErrorDocument 404 I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually very simple to fix:

I just added a rewrite condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/`

Full rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```